# Webkit CSS reset

Tags: css, webkit, reset

There are a few CSS resets out there, but I would like one that resets all browsers to "webkit style". (Hence the webkit browsers are unaffected, just the non-webkit browsers are changed.)

I've found the default webkit stylesheet [here](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/css/html.css) but I cannot naively copy that, since a lot of the property names and variables are webkit-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of painfully trying to recreate a Webkit CSS reset for other web browsers (with webkit recreation hacks), you should instead use the excellent [YUI CSS Reset](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/) and then design your website from there.